# Load Cheerio/jQuery selectors, including methods as strings

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, eval, cheerio

I have a nodejs app, which uses cheerio for extracting parts of html from pages of multiple sites. The app runs through a JSON file and performs the scraping and extraction for each site, for all the URLS, and all [cheerio.js](https://cheerio.js.org/) queries for each URL:

```
"site1":{
    "urls":{
         "http://site1.com/pageA",
         "http://site1.com/pageB",
    },
    "queries":{
          "h1": "$('h1').text()"
          "numbersFromH1": "$('h1').text().match(/\\d+/)[0]"
    } 
}
```

Loading the selectors, e.g. `'h1'` using a variable and having a `.text()` method inside the app would be a no-brainer. However, sometimes I need to `.match()` or .`filter()` etc., sometimes chain the methods.

So, is there a way I could load the whole query (selector+methods) and have cheerio execute it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queries should be functions that take `$` as a parameter - because `$` is dynamic (generated anew for each new document you parse). Then use that `$` which is now in scope inside the function to call what you want on it - without any need for eval. For example:

```
const sites = {
  "site1":{
    "urls":[ // make sure this is an array, not an object
         "http://site1.com/pageA",
         "http://site1.com/pageB",
    ],
    "queries":{
          "h1": $ => $('h1').text(), // make sure to include comma after value
          "numbersFromH1": $ => $('h1').text().match(/\\d+/)[0]
    } 
  }
};

const { site1 } = sites;
// replace with whatever implementation you have that retrieves page text
const pageText = await getPageText(site1.urls[0]);
const firstUrl$ = cheerio.load(pageText);
console.log(site1.queries.h1(firstUrl$));
```

Which should be easily adaptable to loops and more dynamic calls of the URLs and methods.

Comment: Thanks, @CertainPerformance. So If I don't insist on JSON but load a JS object with the actual functions as values (where JSON only allows strings/numbes/objects) instead, as you did, I could simply remove doublequotes surrounding my functions in the current solution. So, is anything stopping me from doing that? IS it a perfromance issue -something to do with `$` being dynamic? I didn't quite catch that..

Comment: No, there's absolutely nothing wrong with writing a plain object literal (not JSON) and include functions in the object. Performance is almost certainly a non-issue here, but turning a string into a function is a lot more expensive than starting out with a function.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question right away: As a hotfix, I use `eval()` to parse the imported query and consume its output.

However, since eval is generally not recommended and I have doubts about its performance, I am still looking for a different solution. E.g by passing the whole query string (not just the selector) to cheerio, somehow..